# How do I restrict all access to a given route in .Net Core 2.1?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

In my .Net Core 2.1 application, controllers are defined as

```
[Route("v1/api/[controller]")]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    // peace & love
}
```

I need to deny access for *all* users to any route that matches the pattern

> v1/api/operations/*

In Startup, we add MvcCore as

```
        services.AddMvcCore()
            .AddAuthorization()
            .AddApiExplorer();
```

and then configure the app to use MVC as

```
        app.UseMvc();
```

How can I ensure that no users can access any resource on the `/operations` route?

Comment: What exactly is the use case here? Why deny all users?

Comment: We are retiring that route but we still want to keep it in the system for the short term behind a toggle switch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I ensure that no users can access any resource on the /operations route?

Using `IActionFilter middleware` you could achieve that:

**RoutingRestrictionMiddleware:**

```cs
public class RoutingRestrictionMiddleware : IActionFilter
{

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {

        if (context.HttpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api/Operations"))
        {

            context.Result = new JsonResult(new { HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized });

        }


    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {

    }
}
```

Point to remember:
`"context.HttpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api/Operations")` - here you can set the `route` you would like to restrict.

**Startup.cs:**

```cs
   services.AddMvc(config =>
        {
            config.Filters.Add(new RoutingRestrictionMiddleware());
        });
```

**Controller Without Route Restriction:**

```cs
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    
    public class OperationsController : ControllerBase
    {
        
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "kiron", "farid" };
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Controller With Route Restriction:**

```cs
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    
    public class OperationsController : ControllerBase
    {
        
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "kiron", "farid" };
        }
    }
}
```

**Route Restriction Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is how I implemented redirecting requests on certain route in ASP.NET6 MVC app with the help of middleware.

Add a custom middleware class.

```
    public class CustomMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public CustomMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    // This method will be invoked for every http request that starts with 'Identity' in it's
    // path string (or for any starting keyword in its path string that matches with what you
    // have registered in Program.cs).
    public Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        // Add as many route cases as you want and handle them as you like. 
        switch (httpContext.Request.Path.Value)
        {
            case "/Identity/Account/SignUp":
                {
                    httpContext.Response.Redirect("/Error/NotAllowed"); // Redirect to not allowed action in error controller.
                }
                break;
        }

        return _next(httpContext);
    }
}
```

In `Program.cs` add this custom middleware to use when the request path matches a criteria. For ex. This will cause all HTTP requests that has a path string starting with `Identity` to pass through your `CustomMiddleware`.

```
app.UseWhen(context => context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/Identity"), appBuilder =>
        {
            appBuilder.UseMiddleware<CustomMiddleware>();
        });
```