# Private API Endpoint in public Azure Serverside Blazor Webapp

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, blazor-server-side, azure-security

I am currently developing a blazor-servers-side application which is publicly accessed. In this application I've got an api-endpoint which will only be accessed from another webapp (also running on azure).

Is there an (easy?) way to restrict access to just this endpoint via Azure? I am currently using an authentication with a bearer token, but want to deny everyone, except the other webapp, access in general.

Splitting my blazor-server-side app and the API into two webapps sadly is not an option.

My App is running on .NET 6

Comment: Use Azure Application Gateway and from here you can do all these tricks.

Comment: You can use `action filter` to restrict specific API endpoints. You could have a look on this [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72297427/how-do-i-restrict-all-access-to-a-given-route-in-net-core-2-1/72298268#72298268)

Comment: Azure Application Gateway seems like the way to go. Thanks, @DA

Comment: You are welcome and glad to know your update.